# Surjective Linear Integer Polynomial

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(X)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients such that $f : \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is onto. Show that $f(X)=\pm X+c$ for some integer $c$.

I was given this question in a lecture on irreducible polynomials. I think a solution using Ostrowski's criterion was presented, but I couldn't quite follow every step. Could someone help? Thanks

Comment: My thoughts would be: if $f$ is even degree, it has either a minimum or maximum value, so it can't be onto.  If $f$ has odd degree $\ge 3$, then $\Delta f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$ or $\Delta f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$, so there's no way $f$ can be onto.  So $f$ has degree 1, and from there it's easy to conclude the coefficient of $x^1$ is $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $x \gg 1$, we have that $f(x) \approx x^{\deg f}$.  For $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, this can't possibly be onto.