# Prove that $f$ is a first degree polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let a polynomial $f$ be in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Assume that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $f(x)=n$ has at least one integer solution. Than prove that $$f(x) = \pm x + c$$ I really don't know to start. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try and prove that with $n$ outside of a range like $[M,-M]$ for some suitable (large) $M$ the values of $f$ are constrained to be in a set that excludes more than $2M+1$ integers. That is, unless A) $f$ is linear, and B) has leading coefficient $\pm1$.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Anyway, I was looking for a more conceptual-algebraic way to solve it, if possible. I remember that I saw this problem solved in an elegant way, a long time ago, but unfortunately I can't recall the proof!

Comment: For $x$ large enough, $f$ is strictly increasing or decreasing. Furthermore, $f(x + 1) - f(x)$ is larger than $1$ unless $f$ fits the expression you have.

Comment: I had a recollection that the same question has been handled (hence no answer from me). Indeed, [here is one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2356786/11619). For better or for worse, the answer/comment there are along the lines of my suggestion. In order not to have this closed as a duplicate may be you need to specify better, what kind of a solution you are looking for?

Comment: A solution that is not "analytic" but instead uses something algebraic like divisors, roots...

Comment: I take it that excludes the first derivative test? That's all you need to develop my comment to a full answer.

Comment: The derivative test is ok as long as you use it for its scope, that is, proving or disproving that you have a multiple root, i guess. I know that what i'm asking is really vague, but i wanted to see if someone knew that proof. It should not be really difficult as I saw it in my second year as an undergraduate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Surjective Linear Integer Polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356786/surjective-linear-integer-polynomial).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_kx^k$ where we shall assume that $a_k\ne0$ and $k>1$.

Let $p$ be a prime greater than $1+|a_1|+|a_2|+...|a_k|$ and suppose that $t$ is an integer solution of $f(x)=a_0+p$.

Then $t(a_1+a_2t+ ...+a_kt^{k-1})=p$ and so $t$ is one of $-1,1,-p,p$.

If $t$ is $-1$ or $1$, then $|a_1|+|a_2|+...|a_k|\ge p$, a contradiction.

So suppose that $t$ is $-p$ or $p$. Then $$|a_k|p^{k-1}\le (1+|a_1|+|a_2|+...|a_{k-1}|)p^{k-2}$$ and so $$p\le (1+|a_1|+|a_2|+...|a_{k-1}|),$$ another contradiction.

Therefore $k$ must be $1$ and, for $t$ is an integer solution of $f(x)=a_0+p$, we have to solve $a_1t=p$. Then $a_1$ is a factor of all possible $p$ and so $a_1$ is $1$ or $-1$, as required.